# In Apex, a package called from SQL Workshop succeeds but from the Application Builder it fails

Tags: oracle-apex

Question from an Apex newby . . .

**Background**

I’m using Oracle Apex to generate reports for a 3rd party SIS (student information system) PowerSchool which resides in its own schema, PS. In PS, I have abstracted key business logic into a collection of custom functions in a single custom package – CKSD_Students.

**Problem**

I have the following simple Oracle query.

```
Select   S.ID                       As Student_ID
       , S.Student_Number           As Student_Number
       , S.LastFirst                As LastFirst
       , ps.cksd_student.get_student_enroll_status(S.Enroll_Status) As Enroll_Status
       , S.Grade_Level              As Grade_Level
       , S.SchoolID                 As SchoolID
       , Sch.Name                   As School_Name
From     Students S
         Inner Join Schools Sch
               On   Sch.School_Number = S.SchoolID
```

It is saved in Oracle Application Express in SQL Workshop as "Saved SQL".

When I open the query and run it, It works and I get the expected results.

Note: "ps.cksd_student" is a custom package has been created in s data base / schema associated with a third party application, PowerSchool.

When I create an Apex report using this query as the SQL Query in the body and press run I get the following error:

```
    is_internal_error: true
    apex_error_code: APEX.AUTHORIZATION.ACCESS_DENIED
    component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_AUTHORIZATION
    component.id: 8270293315071117
    component.name: User still logged into PowerSchool
    error_backtrace:

    ----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
      object      line  object
      handle    number  name
    00007FFBF623C890       642  package body APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_ERROR
    00007FFBF623C890       710  package body APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_ERROR
    00007FFBF623C890      1014  package body APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_ERROR
    00007FFBF7EE0960       793  package body APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_AUTHORIZATION
    00007FFC1790FE50      4518  package body APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW
    00007FFB9D79BF88       173  procedure APEX_050000.F
    00007FFB8554A498         2  anonymous block
```

When I remove the column generated by ps.cksd_student then the report runs fine.

In Oracle, in the PS Schema, I have granted ps.cksd_student execute to the parsing schema and all of the schemas that seem to be connected to Apex, I even granted execute to public and I still get the same error.

- EXECUTE    APEX_050000
- EXECUTE    APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE
- EXECUTE    APEX_LISTENER
- EXECUTE    APEX_PUBLIC_USER
- EXECUTE    APEX_REST_PUBLIC_USER
- EXECUTE    FLOWS_FILES
- EXECUTE    NAVIGATOR_ROLE
- EXECUTE    PSNAVIGATOR
- EXECUTE    PS_APEX (my Parsing Schema)
- EXECUTE    PS_MGMT
- EXECUTE    PUBLIC

One note. This package does log errors into a table in the PS database. I have granted Insert / Update / Select to:

- APEX_050000
- APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE
- APEX_LISTENER
- APEX_PUBLIC_USER
- APEX_REST_PUBLIC_USER
- PS_APEX (my Parsing Schema)
- PS_MGMT

Two questions:

What I find odd is the package is available from SQL Workshop but not an Apex Application.

1) Now that I'm sure the Parsing Schema is covered is there something what else have I missed. Other packages from PS work with Apex so I know this is possible.

2) I know this is throwing an Oracle error somewhere. Can someone help me find it? (probable disk / folder / name)

Thanks,

Eric.

Answer (score 1):

For the query to run

```
grant execute on pkg_owner.package to parsing_schema;
```

It sounds like you've checked your bases there, but that's the fundamental grant.
In SQL Workshop you can check if the "Schema" dropdown is the same as your parsing schema. Some workspaces may be associated with multiple schemas.

However, I'm not sure this is your problem. The error mentions an authorisation scheme, which is something different. Check the Security attribute in the column definition, then check out what that authorisation does to return true/false.

I *think* this authorisation scheme is returning a custom error, related to Powerschool.